# Session Should not expire

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I have 2 application,

- 1 as A application and
- 2 as B application.

Now from A , I am navigating to b application, there I will spend some time. And In B I have a log off button, if user clicks on that, it should come back to application A, with session intact.

I am using J2EE and Weblogic server, Here servers of a and b are also different.
Can any one please help me, I need to complete this work by today eveining.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: single sign on comes to my mind after reading the 1st sentence but your logoff scenario is not not in sync with single sign on...i too am curious if this is possible at all

Comment: Any way, I am using using Single Sign On approach to connect from a to b, Please note it is a Java Solution.

Comment: A and B are on different servers, so anyway their Session IDs will be different. BUT if you are already using an SSO provider, which one is it - is it a product or some in-house solution? Since SSO will not allow this to happen in logoff if it's some product

Comment: Its an Inhouse logic as Santosh mentioned. But at the end what Santhosh does match my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it

1. Assume that a user is on application A with valid session.
2. When you click a link (or post some data) to go on application B, pass some token in query string. (This token may encrypted (username+password+salt)).
3. Application B receives the query string data, decrypts it and authenticates the user.
4. When user clicks log off in application B, the log off handler in application B (it could be a servlet/JSP/Controller/Action etc), does s `response.sendRedirect()` to the application A.
5. which will still have its session intact (provided session has not timed out i.e. the time user spent on application B is less than the session timeout of application A).

Comment: @Kumar, I hope this solves your problem as you mentioned. Plz accept this as an answer.